# Broken apexcharts legend (vue-apexcharts)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, apexcharts

i just create simple piechart with [vue-apexchart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-apexcharts). expected process what I want is,

1. set default config chart
2. mutate the component then re-config the chart based on props
3. render it

i was success this scenario works, but idk what happens with my pie chart. this is my pie chart
[image]

the legend successfully showed, but the legend position is bedhind of pie. i am trying to add offsetY in chart options and legend options. it's still not working.

am i miss something ?

this is my code

```js
<script>
import VueApexCharts from 'vue-apexcharts'

export default {
  components: {
    'apexchart': VueApexCharts,
  },
  props: {
    name: {default: "Durasi Parkir"},
    value: {default: () => ({})},
    height: {default: "320"},
    dir: {default: "ltr"},
    is_showed_legend: {default: true},
    is_floating_legend: {default: true},
    legend_position: {default: "top"},
    legend_vertical_align: {default: "center"},
    legend_horizontal_align: {default: "center"},
    legend_font_size: {default: "14px"},
    legend_x_offset: {default: 0},
    legend_y_offset: {default: 0},
    responsive_breakpoints: {default: 600},
    responsive_chart_height: {default: 240},
    is_responsive_show_legend: {default: false},
    additional_class: {default: ""}
  },
  data: () => ({
    series: [],
    options: {
      labels: [],
      colors: [],
      chart: {
        offsetY: 0, // iam trying to add offset but its still not works
      },
      legend: {
        show: true,
        position: "bottom",
        horizontalAlign: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        floating: false,
        fontSize: "14px",
        offsetX: 0,
        offsetY: 10,
      },
      responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 0,
        options: {
          chart: {
            height: 0
          },
          legend: {
            show: false
          },
        }
      }]
    }
  }),
  created() {
    this.processThemingChart()
  },
  methods: {
    formatChartColor(index = 0) {
      let array_colors = [this.$utility.getPrimaryColor(), "#b6b6b6", "#5fa2f4", "#5abf78",
        "#6983aa", "#e97171", "#ede682", "#ba7967", "#f1c5c5", "#f69e7b"]
      if (index) return array_colors[index]
      else return array_colors
    },

    processFillChartColor() {
      this.options.colors = this.formatChartColor()
    },

    processFillChartOption() {
      this.options.legend.position = this.legend_position
      this.options.legend.fontSize = this.legend_font_size
      this.options.legend.show = this.is_showed_legend
      this.options.legend.floating = this.is_floating_legend
      this.options.responsive[0].breakpoint = this.responsive_breakpoints
      this.options.responsive[0].options.chart.height = this.responsive_chart_height
      this.options.responsive[0].options.legend.show = this.is_responsive_show_legend
      this.options.legend.horizontalAlign = this.legend_horizontal_align
      this.options.legend.verticalAlign = this.legend_vertical_align
      this.options.legend.offsetY = this.legend_y_offset
      this.options.legend.offsetX = this.legend_x_offset
    },

    processThemingChart() {
      this.processFillChartColor()
      this.processFillChartOption()
      this.processDataChart()
    },

    processDataChart() {
      this.series = []
      this.options.labels = []
      this.value.forEach(item => {
        this.series.push(item.value)
        this.options.labels.push(item.text)
      })
    },

    processFillChart() {
      try {
        (this.value !== '') ? this.processDataChart() : ''
      } catch (e) {
        this.$sentry.captureException(e, `user gagal merender grafik ${this.name}`)
      }
    },
  }
}
</script>
<template>
  <apexchart :class="`apex-charts ${additional_class}`" :height="height" type="pie" :dir="dir"
             :series="series" :options="options" 
  ></apexchart>
</template>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this translates to `vue-apexcharts` but the correct syntax for the legend is probably `position: 'bottom'` as shown here: https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/legend/ Also, a quick and easy way of debugging/fixing this is to inspect the apexCharts component with your Vue devtools and see which props it does have. The cool thing is that you can dynamically edit those and see if it do have an impact. Otherwise, you can always make a CSS fix with a `margin-top` or alike. EDIT: nvm I was looking the `props` object, my bad. The other part of my message stays valid still.

Comment: change offsetY: 10